# Is it ever possible to add a dependency to a deployed WAR without modifying/redeploying the WAR

Tags: deployment, war, weblogic-10.x, dependency-management, circular-dependency

We have an application XYZ that displays forms to a user. We would like to distribute this application and allow external develops to create their own forms (extending interfaces provided by application XYZ) and deploy those forms in a way that application XYZ can display them without having to be modified itself. Application XYZ knows which forms it can display by looking up a config file which lists all of the form classes available (these are then instantiated reflectively).

We are using Weblogic 10.3 as the application server and the application is a GWT / Java app.

As far as I'm aware the scenario I've described would not be possible as application XYZ will need to be recompiled and redeployed with the new dependency added to the classpath. I am hoping that someone can tell me otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The Servlet specification states that each WAR file is deployed on it's own isolated class loader. This enables the isolation of multiple web applications, running on the same servlet container instance.

The [tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) describes the relationship of the various class-loaders very well. (Considering Tomcat was the reference implementation for servlets, Weblogic should execute in a similar manner)

So an alternative to recompiling you WAR would be to place these extra custom jars into the "$CATALINA_BASE/lib" directory (or Weblogic's equivolent).

However I see a couple of implementation issues to be aware of:

1. Your application would need to be compiled against a fixed
   interface. This would enable users to substitute a run-time implementation of
   those classes.
2. The custom jars would be shared across all
   instances of your application. This might rule out running older versions of your app on the same appserver instance.
3. Expect deployment problems... Think about how your application would react to missing dependencies. Users won't understand a Java stacktrace :-)

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your response. I've had a look at weblogic documentation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/programming/libraries.html and found that I can do something similar to what you have described using shared J2EE libraries / optional packages. However the recompiling problem would still exist I believe because in order to reference the shared libraries you still need to add a reference in the application manifest file no?

Comment: You could put the configuration file onto the classpath, external to the application. Perhaps a better idea is investigate how various open source products support their custom plugins. Normally there is a published Java interface(s) thru which the plug-in both registers and communicates with the application. To avoid a centralised configuration files the application extensions are plaved onto the classpath and discovered at runtime.